# jQuery range increase variables

Tags: jquery

I have difficulty how to do that:

- I have job duration (range slider)
- 4 variables:

  - first hour - £30
  - 30 min - £15
  - every next hour - £20
  - 30 min - £10

I've tried with array and the correct price for each hour (max 8hours), but if I change some of the prices I have to change (recalculate) all the array. So how can I make it that way:

- if slider val is 0 - £30 (1 hour)
- if slider val is 1 - $45 (1h 30min)
- if slider val is 2 - £50 (2 hours)
- if slider val is 3 - £60 (2h 30min)
- and so on.

```
var duration_array = ['1 Hour 00 Minutes', 
                        '1 Hour 30 Minutes',
                        '2 Hours 00 Minutes',
                        '2 Hours 30 Minutes',
                        '3 Hours 00 Minutes',
                        '3 Hours 30 Minutes',
                        '4 Hours 00 Minutes',
                        '4 Hours 30 Minutes',
                        '5 Hours 00 Minutes',
                        '5 Hours 30 Minutes',
                        '6 Hours 00 Minutes',
                        '6 Hours 30 Minutes',
                        '7 Hours 00 Minutes',
                        '7 Hours 30 Minutes',
                        '8 Hours 00 Minutes'
                        ];

$(document).on('input', '#duration_slider', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#duration_output').html(duration_array[value]);

    var a = 51;
    var b = 25.50;
    var c = 39;
    var d = 19.50;
});
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do.  Are you using a [jQueryUI slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/)?  There is no slider code here?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, he is talking about Range Slider which is in HTML, like this

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

Comment: Please show your HTML, particularly the `#duration_slider` element.

Comment: @kmoser not pretty sure, but I think it is selected with some option each represents the hours. his question is not clear, hope he updates it. **Text input**

Comment: i'm using  <input type="range"...>
so what i need is when i select specific duration, to calculate that price.
I need 4 variables:
1. first hour price
2. first hour and half price
3. every next hour
4. every 30 min added to that next hour..

Comment: Why do you need 4 variables? The slider can only ever be at one position at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you have 2 pricing rules:

- when the time is less than 2 hours, it is just `hours * £30`;
- when the time is 2+ hours, it is the cost of the first hour, plus `extra hours * £20`;

Checking [the docs for range inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range), we can also use a `step` attribute.  Since your pricing goes up in half-hour increments, we can use a `step` value of `0.5` to get exactly how many hours you need to charge for.

So putting that all together:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#duration_slider', function() {
    // Use parseFloat to make sure hours is a number so we can do math with it
    var hours = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var cost = 0;
    
    $('#hours').html(hours);
    
    if (hours < 2) {
        cost = hours * 30;
    } else {
        // Cost of first hour is 30; calculate the remaining cost 
        // and add it to the first hour cost.
        hours = hours - 1;
        cost = (hours * 20) + 30;
    }

    $('#duration_output').html(cost);
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="8" step="0.5" class="slider" id="duration_slider">

<div>
    <p>Hours: <span id="hours">1</span></p>
    <p>Cost: £<span id="duration_output">30</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to look at the index number of the slider and convert it to your final price:

```js
var duration_array = [
    '1 Hour 00 Minutes', 
    '1 Hour 30 Minutes',
    '2 Hours 00 Minutes',
    '2 Hours 30 Minutes',
    '3 Hours 00 Minutes',
    '3 Hours 30 Minutes',
    '4 Hours 00 Minutes',
    '4 Hours 30 Minutes',
    '5 Hours 00 Minutes',
    '5 Hours 30 Minutes',
    '6 Hours 00 Minutes',
    '6 Hours 30 Minutes',
    '7 Hours 00 Minutes',
    '7 Hours 30 Minutes',
    '8 Hours 00 Minutes'
];

$(document).on('input', '#duration_slider', function() {
    var value = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    $('#duration_output').html(duration_array[value]);

    let price;
    switch ( value ) {
        case 0:
            price = 30;
            break;
        case 1:
            price = 45;
            break;
        default:
            price = (value * 25) - 15 * (value - 2)
            break;
    }
    
    $('#price_output').html(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="0" max="14" id="duration_slider">
<br>
<div id="duration_output"></div>
$<span id="price_output"></span>
```